# EmojiCompat fetchFont result is not OK

Tags: android, android-support-library

My app uses EmojiCompat with font downloading (not bundled) and a big amount of my users are reporting the following error:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: fetchFonts result is not OK. (2)
   at android.support.text.emoji.FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig$FontRequestMetadataLoader.createMetadata(FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig.java:307)
   at android.support.text.emoji.FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig$FontRequestMetadataLoader.access$100(FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig.java:164)
   at android.support.text.emoji.FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig$FontRequestMetadataLoader$1.run(FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig.java:218)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I could not find any reference to this error message and I have no idea what is causing it. My guess is that it is an internal problem on the Google Play Services font downloading.

Edit on 2017-11-13: Still happening on support library 27.0.0.

Edit on 2017-11-15: My configuration.

On my Application class, on the onCreate():

```
val fontRequest = FontRequest(
        "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        "com.google.android.gms",
        "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
        R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs)
val config = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest)
config.setReplaceAll(true)
EmojiCompat.init(config)
```

Parsing text with Emoji:

```
EmojiCompat.get().registerInitCallback(object : EmojiCompat.InitCallback() {
    override fun onInitialized() {
        text = EmojiCompat.get().process(charSequence)
    }

    override fun onFailed(throwable: Throwable?) {
        throwable?.let { Crashlytics.logException(throwable) }
    }
})
```

The above exception is logged on the Crashlytics.logException()

Comment: exact same issue here

Comment: Can you share your `EmojiCompat` configuration?

Comment: @azizbekian I have updated the issue with my code config

Comment: Miquel, does this still happen?

Comment: I have stopped tracking it, so I am not sure anymore :) Will mark your answer as valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is more related to Google Play Services and network connection. Added comments to the bug created at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64430424#comment8

Comment: Will adding the retry policy fix this issue? What should be the ideal retry delay?